How can I handle and debug errors in complex asynchronous applications?
I'm working on an application with multiple asynchronous operations, and I'm finding it challenging to manage and debug errors effectively. When dealing with async code—especially when using a mix of promises and async/await—I'm looking for the best practices to catch and handle errors consistently.
Specifically, I’d like to know:
How do you handle errors in async operations to ensure they don’t go unhandled?
Are there preferred tools or techniques you rely on to debug complex async workflows?
What strategies do you use to pinpoint issues efficiently in nested or chained async functions?
Any advice on tools or general approaches that could help streamline async debugging would be appreciated.
What I’ve Tried:
Standard Try-Catch Blocks: I've wrapped async functions in try-catch blocks, but this becomes difficult to manage with deeply nested or chained async calls, where errors still occasionally go unhandled or get lost.
.catch() on Promises: Using .catch() for promises worked to an extent, but tracking the flow in complex chains makes it challenging to identify exactly where things go wrong, especially when multiple promises run concurrently.
Logging with Console Statements: I tried using console.log() at different points, but this quickly got messy in larger operations, making it hard to follow error origins and connections between async tasks.
Debugging Tools: I’ve used Chrome DevTools and Node’s debugging capabilities, but they become harder to use with asynchronous functions, as the call stack often doesn’t reveal the full path of async operations clearly.
Each of these methods has helped to some degree, but none have provided a clear, manageable way to handle and debug async errors in a large-scale setup. I’m hoping to find more effective strategies or tools that can simplify this process.

"errors still occasionally go unhandled or get lost." - that shouldn't happen. If you have unhandled errors, it's most likely you forgot to await a promise (or the promise wasn't rejected properly in the first place, with the async code just throwing the error elsewhere). If you loose errors, it's most likely some broken catch code that ignores the error and fails to re-throw it.

"try-catch blocks […] becomes difficult to manage with deeply nested or chained async calls" - it's the same with synchronous calls though. More complex code just has more complex error handling, there's not really a way to avoid that. There are no techniques that are specific to asynchronous operations.

Please provide a reproducible example of "where errors still occasionally go unhandled or get lost". You could be looking at code executed outside of Promise detection of errors without realizing it.

Handling and debugging asynchronous operations can indeed become complex, especially in large-scale applications where multiple async tasks interact.
Centralized Error Handling
Global Error Handlers:

Unhandled Promise Rejections: In Node.js, you can listen for unhandled promise rejections and handle them appropriately.
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection:', reason);
  //log the error and exit the process if necessary
});



Utilizing Async/Await Consistently.
Mixing Promise Chaining (then/catch) with async/await can lead to confusion. Consider standardizing your codebase to use async/await wherever possible.

Await All Promises: Ensure that you either await or return all promises in async functions to handle errors properly.
If you are awaiting a promise, then you should always throw the error from catch block. Also, awaiting should be done in try-catch.
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const data = await getData();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle error
    throw err; // Re-throw if necessary
  }
}



Note - Always await top most async function
